# How do I do an average plus count of a column using pandas data frame?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

This code looks really stupid but this is a basic representation of the problem I've been dealing with all day - I have 3 columns, type, day and month. I'd like to count the number of dogs/cats by day, and then average it out over the month.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = {'Type':['Dog', 'Cat', 'Cat', 'Cat', 'Dog', 'Dog', 'Dog', 'Cat'], 'Day':[1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4], 'Month': [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2]}
newDF = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Which creates a dataframe that looks like this:

```
Type|Day|Month
---------
Dog|1|1
Cat|1|1
Cat|2|1
Cat|2|1
Dog|3|2
Dog|3|2
Dog|4|2
Cat|4|2
```

What I'm trying to do here is create a table below showing this:

```
Type | Month1 | Month2
------------------------

Dog  |   1    |   1.5

Cat  |   1.5  |    1
```

So basically, I just want to use some combination of pivot table or groupby to create a pivot_table containing the count of number of cats / dogs per day, and then average that out over the month. For some reason, I just can't manage to figure it out. Can someone smart enough with pandas please help? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two `groupbys` + `unstack`

```
(newDF.groupby(['Type', 'Day', 'Month']).size()
      .groupby(level=[0,2]).mean()
      .unstack()
      .add_prefix('Month').rename_axis(None, 1))
```

Output:

```
      Month1  Month2
Type                
Cat      1.5     1.0
Dog      1.0     1.5
```

Comment: Thank you! Thank you for going the extra step to help rename the columns too. This is exactly what I needed.

Comment: No problem! It's not too difficult when there's sample data and the expected output  :D

Answer (score 2):

Just a `groupby` combined with an `unstack` and `mean`:

```
df.groupby(df.columns.tolist()) \ 
  .size() \
  .unstack(level='Day') \
  .mean(axis=1) \
  .unstack(level='Month')
```

Output:

```
Month    1    2
Type           
Cat    1.5  1.0
Dog    1.0  1.5
```

Comment: Just realized I'm not quite in the shape you're looking for. ALollz's answer gets you closer to what you want. I've made an edit to my answer to more closely reflect what you're looking for.

Comment: Tbh both of your answers are fantastic. Thank you!